# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits) and unknown display and can't change resolution in display setting

Tags: drivers, grub2, nvidia, graphics, display-resolution

_os "nvidia iso" today.(ubuntu 20.04 LTS)
but i dual boot it with windows 10 with grub bootloader.
in about menu it shows me graphics "llvmpipe (LLVM 11.0.0, 256 bits)" but my gpu is GeForce GT 730.
and in my display settings it shows me "unknown display" and my resolution is locked in 1024x768 (4:3)

i tried to change grub setting in /etc/defualt/grub
but it didn't work. i changed

from
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
to
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

i do not know what is my nvidia driver version and i do not if it is updated or not i just run sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
i tried to find out my driver version with: nvidia-smi but it showed me this
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

when i open nvidia x server settings it shows me a blank window.

i am new to linux and i do not know what to do please help me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

```
sudo apt remove xorg
sudo apt install xorg
```

**Leave A Like, I Hope This Helped You!!**