# How to solve recurrent resolution issue on Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display-resolution

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 on a machine that has (based on `lspci -v`): `VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corp. GK208B [GeForce GT 730]...`, although on the system ABOUT the graphics shows as `llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)`.

The resolution should be 1920x1080 but the screen does not have this resolutoin. I solve a first issue of this kind with the command `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall; sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470`. I solved a second issue of this kind, on the same machine, with the same command, and a third issue as well.

The it happened again, but this time the command did not work. To note that the drivers are already installed. I tried to install a newer driver with `sudo ubuntu-drivers install nvidia:525` but it did not work.

I tried to force the resolution by changing the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"` on /etc/default/grub and reload with `sudo update-grub`. But it did not work. I also tried to reinstall xorg, [as shown in this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353332/ubuntu-20-04-lts-llvmpipe-llvm-11-0-0-256-bits-and-unknown-display-and-can), but did not work.

How can I force the resolution to 1920 x 1080 once and for all?

Why do I have the line `llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)` instead of an `NVIDIA` one in system:About? Is that the problem? If yes, how do I change it?

Was the modification of grub a good approach?

Shall I follow this [post about disabling secure boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1241103/not-detecting-nvidia-but-detect-llvmpipe-llvm-6-0-256-bits)? In my configuration, I have a fast boot, then a secure boot option #1 `ubuntu (SATA6G_5:...)` active and a `SATA6G_5:...` inactive. Shall I disable it? And if yes, how will the machine know where to find the booting files (for it will not know where to find SATS6G_5 anymore...)?

To note that I have other machines with Ubuntu 22.04, but this error occurs always and only on a specific machine. The machine that gives resolution problem has:

```
$ uname -a
Linux whopper 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

One machine that does not give resolution problem has

```
$ uname -a
Linux behemoth 5.19.0-40-generic #41~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Mar 31 16:00:14 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Is there something wrong with the hardware of this machine? Perhaps either the video card or the mother board have a glitch?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, they all run 22.04

Comment: Add this info to the question not as a comment please.

Answer (score 1):

Some 48 hours earlier my perfectly workable 22.04 with no resolution issue,  got frozen on 1080 x 720 just out of blue.  Two days later after trying everything  I have found on the net, several times, hitting my head to the wall to relax myself between tries, I have finally decided to remove all **Nvidia** drivers. Solution for uninstalling **Nvidia** drivers also suggested reinstalling ubuntu-desktop.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

reference site: [How can I uninstall a nvidia driver completely ?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206283/how-can-i-uninstall-a-nvidia-driver-completely)

And that's it. After two days everything started working properly again. But what did I do wrong two days earlier??? Can't be out of blue. I'm too old, and smart enough, to believe in "out of blue" bulsh..* in IT world.

Well, some 72 howers earlier on an usual

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

my 22.04 told me something like this

> "**The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer
> required:**   dctrl-tools dkms libnvidia-cfg1-470
> libnvidia-compute-470:i386   libnvidia-decode-470
> libnvidia-decode-470:i386 libnvidia-egl-wayland1  
> libnvidia-encode-470 libnvidia-encode-470:i386 libnvidia-extra-470  
> libnvidia-fbc1-470 libnvidia-fbc1-470:i386 libnvidia-gl-470  
> libnvidia-ifr1-470 libnvidia-ifr1-470:i386 libxnvctrl0 pkg-config  
> screen-resolution-extra xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470 **Use 'sudo apt
> autoremove' to remove them."**

And I did it! I just typed `sudo apt autoremove`. Shit happened after the first reboot 24 hours later when I completely lost this simple step from my mind.

All problems with freezing resolution I have found on the internet are somehow related to **Nvidia**. Looks like **Nvidia** has some issue with Ubuntu distribution :). When my headache, which is probably the result of relaxation, passes, I'll definitely try to freeze my monitor again. By just typing `sudo apt autoremove`

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it with `sudo apt-get install update-manager-core`, now the resulting is back as it should.

Comment: i tried this and it didnt work. can you give more information on yours if it worked for you. Im currently having the same issue right now.

Comment: I can give an update. Eventually, I had to reinstall Ubuntu. The resolution lasted less than a week, and the issue suddenly returned as before. I tried the solutions above, but no good. Then I even lost the Wi-Fi, so I had to change the whole machine. I think there is an ongoing serious issue in hardware management.